# IntelliJ IDEA can not find TestingServer on my classpath

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-curator

I can find `TestingServer` in my External Libraries (see screenshot below), but why can I not import it? Is the `curator-test` library not in my classpath?

I'm using:
• IntelliJ Idea           2017.1.2
• Spring Boot          1.5.3.RELEASE
• Apache Curator    2.11.1

My pom.xml looks as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.fan.curator</groupId>
    <artifactId>fan-curator-demo01</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>fan-curator-demo01</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
            <artifactId>curator-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

These are my external libraries in IntelliJ IDEA.

[image: Screenshot of External Libraries in IntelliJ IDEA]

This is the error I get; TestingServer cannot be imported.

[image: Screenshot of error showing TestingServer cannot be imported]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out why.
Spring boot make the `curator-test`'s scope `test`(I don't know why).
So I add a `compile` scope to its artifact, and it's ok now.

Comment: Scope "test" is correct as this is normally used only for testing.